# Python - plot difference between graphs

Tags: python, plot

I have two functions,

*One calculates the natural log of x over a range.

*The other calculates an approximative value of ln(x) over the same range. Like this:

```
def approx_ln(x,n):
    a=(1+x)/2
    g=sqrt(x)
    for i in range(1, n):
        a=(a+g)/2
        g=sqrt(a*g)
    return((x-1)/a)

    xlist=list(range(100,1000))
    ylist=[log(x) for x in xlist]
    ylistapproxn2= [approx_ln(x,n=2) for x in xlist]
```

I want to create a graph of the difference between the values of these two functions over a range of x. But just subtracting one function from the other in the following way does not work :(

```
plot(xlist, (ylist-ylistapproxn2), linestyle='-')
```

How could one do this?

Comment: make a [mcve].  Read [ask]

Comment: [y1-y2 for y1,y2 in zip(ylist,ylistapproxn2)]

Comment: If you want subtractable arrays you can use numpy